# Unable to look up IP address in 64-bit VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dns, nslookup

My base problem is that I have a spreadsheet with 10's of thousands of FQDN (fully qualified domain name) entries that I need to check if the FQDN is a valid DNS entry on the public internet. I am doing a DNS lookup of each FQDN and would like to specify a public DNS server. If the call to the DNS returns an IP address, I will assume the FQDN is valid. I am working in excel 64-bit, but need a solution that will also compile and work in 32-bit, so I want the same source code to be able to be compiled in both.  Since there are so many rows in the spreadsheet, I don't want to use a function that creates a temporary file for each lookup.  (I am OCD about unneeded temporary files when a system call is available).

I believe that the function "getaddrinfoex" provides the ability to specify what name server is queried, but I have not been able to find any VBA snippets that use getaddrinfoex or the lesser version of getaddrinfo (which does not allow specifying the DNS server). I have found several examples of calls to gethostbyname, but all are for 32-bit Excel.  Also, Microsoft has published that gethostbyname has been deprecated (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524(v=vs.85).aspx), so I was trying to use the recommended replacement getaddrinfo

[How can I make a network connection with Visual Basic from Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177492/how-can-i-make-a-network-connection-with-visual-basic-from-microsoft-access/41730492?noredirect=1#comment70655861_41730492)

The snippet posted in the answer by @david in the question I linked above looks to have the proper syntax to be both 32-bit and 64-bit compatible. But the example did not include the call to gethostbyname, it only provided the declaration of the function.

Is getaddrinfoex available in VBA? Does someone have an example of using getaddrinfoex which will work in both 32-bit and 64-bit?

I would appreciate any help. I have not coded in MANY years, so my skills are very dated. Thus I am doing a lot of searches to find what I need.

Here is the code I have created from combining various searches on-line.

```
Private Type HOSTENT
   hName As LongPtr
   hAliases As LongPtr
   hAddrType As Integer
   hLen As Integer
   hAddrList As LongPtr
End Type

#if Not VBA7 then
   ' used by 32-bit compiler
   Private Declare Function gethostbyname Lib "wsock32.dll" _
       (ByVal HostName As String) As LongPtr

   Private Declare Function getaddrinfo Lib "wsock32.dll" _
       (ByVal HostName As String) As LongPtr

   Public Declare Function WSAStartup Lib "wsock32.dll" _
       (ByVal wVersionRequired As Long, lpWSADATA As WSADATA) As LongPtr
#else
' used by 64-bit compiler
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function gethostbyname Lib "wsock32.dll" _
       (ByVal HostName As String) As LongPtr

   Private Declare PtrSafe Function getaddrinfo Lib "wsock32.dll" _
       (ByVal HostName As String) As LongPtr

   Public Declare PtrSafe Function WSAStartup Lib "wsock32.dll" _
       (ByVal wVersionRequired As Long, lpWSADATA As WSADATA) As LongPtr

#endif

Public Function GetIPAddressFromHostName(ByVal HostName As String) _
               As LongPtr

    Dim HostEntry As HOSTENT
    Dim HostEntry2 as HOSTENT
    Dim HostEntryPtr As LongPtr
    Dim HostEntryPtr2 As LongPtr
    Dim IPAddressesPtr As LongPtr
    Dim Result As Long

    If InitializeSockets Then
        ' I added the call do getaddrinfo as an example
        ' I have been able to get it to work at all
        HostEntryPtr2 = getaddrinfo(HostName & vbNullChar)

        HostEntryPtr = gethostbyname(HostName & vbNullChar)
        If HostEntryPtr > 0 Then
                 CopyMemory HostEntry, ByVal HostEntryPtr, Len(HostEntryPtr)
                 CopyMemory IPAddressesPtr, ByVal HostEntry.hAddrList, _
                     Len(IPAddressesPtr)
                 CopyMemory Result, ByVal IPAddressesPtr, Len(Result)
                 GetIPAddressFromHostName = Result
              End If
           End If  
End Function

Public Function InitializeSockets() As Boolean
    ' Initialize Windows sockets. 
   Dim WinSockData As WSADATA
   InitializeSockets = WSAStartup(WS_VERSION_REQD, WinSockData) = 0   
End Function
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd check out this post:  http://jayteknews.blogspot.no/2011/08/excel-user-defined-function-nslookup.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I have looked at that post previously. It uses a temporary file for each DNS lookup.  Because I will populate this spreadsheet daily with 10,000+ FQDN and will do that for several weeks, I really don't want to creaete/delete that many temporary files.  It is also a speed of execution issue.  VBA is not the fastest thing in the world when you execute a function that many times, adding in the overhead of a create/delete of a file, would make updating the spreadsheet too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working now as long as it is not moved to an add-in (.xlam).  If I move it to an add-in this exact same code crashes on the call to getaddrinfo.  I will continue to work on that.

The procedure requires one argument (hostname passed as a string).  The second argument is the maximum number of IP addresses to return (passed as an integer), but is optional.  If the second argument is blank, all IP address are returned.  When set to a value other than zero, that value will be the maximum number of ip addresses for the host.

```
Private Const AF_UNSPEC As Long = 0
Private Const AF_INET As Long = 2
Private Const AF_INET6 As Long = 23

Private Const SOCK_STREAM As Long = 1
Private Const INADDR_ANY As Long = 0
Private Const IPPROTO_TCP As Long = 6

' Getaddrinfo return status codes
Private Const WAS_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = 8    '  Insufficient memory available.
Private Const WASEINVAL = 10022    '  Invalid argument.
Private Const WASESOCKTNOSUPPORT = 10044     '  Socket type not supported.
Private Const WASEAFNOSUPPORT = 10047    '  Address family not supported by protocol family.
Private Const WASNOTINITIALISED = 10093    '  Successful WSAStartup not yet performed.
Private Const WASTYPE_NOT_FOUND = 10109    '  Class type not found.
Private Const WASHOST_NOT_FOUND = 11001    '  Host not found.
Private Const WASTRY_AGAIN = 11002    '  Nonauthoritative host not found.
Private Const WASNO_RECOVERY = 11003    '  This is a nonrecoverable error.
Private Const WASNO_DATA = 11004    '  Valid name, no data record of requested type.

'AI_flags
Private Const AI_PASSIVE As Long = &H1
Private Const ai_canonName As Long = &H2
Private Const AI_NUMERICHOST As Long = &H4
Private Const AI_ALL As Long = &H100
Private Const AI_ADDRCONFIG As Long = &H400
Private Const AI_V4MAPPED As Long = &H800
Private Const AI_NON_AUTHORITATIVE As Long = &H4000
Private Const AI_SECURE As Integer = &H8000
Private Const AI_RETURN_PREFERRED_NAMES As Long = &H10000
Private Const AI_FQDN As Long = &H20000
Private Const AI_FILESERVER As Long = &H40000

Dim hSocket As Long
Dim sServer As String

' To initialize Winsock.
Private Type WSADATA
   wVersion                               As Integer
   wHighVersion                           As Integer
   szDescription(256 + 1)                 As Byte
   szSystemstatus(128 + 1)                As Byte
   iMaxSockets                            As Integer
   iMaxUpdDg                              As Integer
   lpVendorInfo                           As Long
End Type

Private Type in_addr
   s_addr   As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type sockaddr_in
    sin_family          As Integer  '2 bytes
    sin_port            As Integer  '2 bytes
    sin_addr            As in_addr  '4 bytes or 8 bytes
    sin_zero(7)         As Byte     '8 bytes
End Type                            'Total 16 bytes or 24 bytes

Private Type sockaddr
    sa_family           As Integer  '2 bytes
    sa_data(25)         As Byte     '26 bytes
End Type                            'Total 28 bytes

Private Type addrinfo
    ai_flags As Long
    ai_family As Long
    ai_socktype As Long
    ai_protocol As Long
    ai_addrlen As Long
    ai_canonName As LongPtr 'strptr
    ai_addr As LongPtr 'p sockaddr
    ai_next As LongPtr 'p addrinfo
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function API_Socket Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "socket" (ByVal af As Long, ByVal stype As Long, ByVal Protocol As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function API_GetAddrInfo Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "getaddrinfo" (ByVal NodeName As String, ByVal ServName As String, ByVal lpHints As LongPtr, lpResult As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ntohs Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal netshort As Long) As Integer


Public Function NameToIPaddress(hostname As String, Optional MaxReturn As Integer = 0) As String
    Dim sa_local As sockaddr_in
    Dim sa_dest As sockaddr
    Dim lRet As Long
    Dim Hints As addrinfo
    Dim ptrResult As LongPtr
    Dim IPaddress As String
    Dim AddressList As String
    Dim AddressType As Long
    Dim Cnt As Integer

    AddressType = AF_INET

    If hostname = "" Then
        NameToIPaddress = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Create TCP socket
    hSocket = API_Socket(AddressType, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
    If hSocket = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Failed to create socket!")
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Populate the local sockaddr
    sa_local.sin_family = AddressType
    sa_local.sin_port = ntohs(0&)
    sa_local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY

    'Recover info about the destination.
    'Hints.ai_flags = AI_NON_AUTHORITATIVE
    Hints.ai_flags = 0
    Hints.ai_family = AddressType
    sServer = hostname & vbNullChar 'Null terminated string
    sServer = hostname
    lRet = API_GetAddrInfo(sServer, 0, VarPtr(Hints), ptrResult)
    If lRet <> 0 Then
        If lRet = WASHOST_NOT_FOUND Then
            NameToIPaddress = "not found"
            Exit Function
        End If
        Dim errorText As String
        Select Case lRet
            Case WAS_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY
                errorText = "Insufficient memory available"
            Case WASEINVAL
                errorText = "Invalid argument"
            Case WASESOCKTNOSUPPORT
                errorText = "Socket type not supported"
            Case WASEAFNOSUPPOR
                errorText = "Address family not supported by protocol family"
            Case WASNOTINITIALISED
                errorText = "Successful WSAStartup not yet performed"
            Case WASTYPE_NOT_FOUND
                errorText = "Class type not found"
            Case WASHOST_NOT_FOUND
                errorText = "Host not found"
            Case WASTRY_AGAIN
                errorText = "Nonauthoritative host not found"
            Case WASNO_RECOVERY
                errorText = "This is a nonrecoverable error"
            Case WASNO_DATA
                errorText = "Valid name, no data record of requested type"
            Case Else
                errorText = "unknown error condition"
        End Select
        'MsgBox ("Error in GetAddrInfo:  " & lRet & " - " & errorText)
        NameToIPaddress = "#Error in lookup"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Cnt = 0
    Hints.ai_next = ptrResult   'Pointer to first structure in linked list

    Do While Hints.ai_next > 0 And (Cnt < MaxReturn Or MaxReturn = 0)
       CopyMemory Hints, ByVal Hints.ai_next, LenB(Hints) 'Copy next address info to Hints
       CopyMemory sa_dest, ByVal Hints.ai_addr, LenB(sa_dest)    'Save sockaddr portion
       Select Case sa_dest.sa_family
           Case AF_INET
               IPaddress = sa_dest.sa_data(2) & "." & sa_dest.sa_data(3) & "." & sa_dest.sa_data(4) & "." & sa_dest.sa_data(5)
           Case AF_INET6
               IPaddress = sa_dest.sa_data(0) & ":" & sa_dest.sa_data(1) & ":" & sa_dest.sa_data(2) & "::" & sa_dest.sa_data(3) & ":" & sa_dest.sa_data(4)
           Case Else
               IPaddress = ""
       End Select
       Cnt = Cnt + 1
       If AddressList = "" Then
           AddressList = IPaddress
       Else
          AddressList = AddressList & "," & IPaddress
       End If
    Loop
    NameToIPaddress = AddressList
End Function
```